# Using Deep Learning for sequencial data

Tags: deep-learning

I have a big number of sequences of labeled Data and I would like to use Deep Learning to classify them. For example:
I have n files (f1 f2 f3...fn) Each one has a very large number of sequences:

f1

0 15 0 0 0 2...

0 2 4 4 4 8...

1 0 0 5 7 8...

0 3 5 6 0 22...

f2

0 0 0 0 1 0...

1 0 3 0 5 0...

3 0 0 0 11 4...

2 0 7 8 1 3...

Now for a given sequence (e.g: 1 4 3 0 0 0 0....), the (deep learning) program should be able to classify it in the correct file. Could you explain in easy_to_understand way how to tackle this problem using deep learning ?
I am planning to use R and/or Python. I will be very glad to hear about some useful deep learning libraries for such problems.

Comment: Theano, Torch, DeepLearning4j, 0xData-H2o, Berkely Caffe

Comment: what are the steps for tackling this problem using one or some of those libraries ?

Answer (score 0):

No sure if this problem really needs ML (or even deep learning) to solve. If you can find a unique sequence of each file, then a simple mapping can do the job (since you said "Each one has a very large number of sequences").

If not the case, then this is a [classification problem](https://www.google.ie/search?q=classification%20problem&oq=classification%20problem&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). In a nutshell,  in classification problem, we learn the pattern of X to predict y. In your case, X would be the sequence in a file, y would be the file name. Before go into deep learning, i recommend you take a look at [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_classification_20newsgroups.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use LSTM for this task. Sequential task is a natural use of LSTM. You can use python, has several libraries such as theano, pybrain, tensorflow, torch, etc. 
For example, sound is a sequential phenomenon and modern speech recognition(google,microsoft,baidu) use LST for this task.